# ionic/angularJs1-ui does not scroll when keyboard appears if ng-if condition is used for ion-content for android device

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, scroll, keyboard

ionic1/angularJs1-ui does not scroll up when keyboard appears if ng-if condition is used for ion-content for android device